# Add a dropdown menu using Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm creating a menu using Tkinter and I'm trying to add a recent file option to the menu which leads to a dropdown menu when hovered over. An example of this is shown below: 
[image: Screenshot of Google Chrome with dropdown menu.]

As you can see in the dropdown menu, there is an option to hover over an arrow which leads to another dropdown menu. This is what I'm trying to replicate using Tkinter. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you done any research? There are many examples of multilevel menus on the internet, and the methods to create it are documented.

Comment: @BryanOakley ive tried doing some research but I didnt know that it was called a multi level menu so I was just getting a normal menu, thanks ill look into it :)

Comment: It's not called a multilevel menu. It's called a "cascade menu". Multilevel is just a description.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ive found what Im looking for now thanks to your help, appreciate it!